# Edição de JFrames

Tags: java, jframe

Tenho o seguinte código que corresponde ao Painel do cabeçalho mas não me da o output pretendido que esta na imagem .Alguem me pode ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class PainelEstadoContacto extends JPanel{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador;
private JButton offline;
private JButton online;


public PainelEstadoContacto(JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador) {
    this.janelaUtilizador=janelaUtilizador;

    offline=new JButton("OFFLINE");
    offline.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    online= new JButton("ONLINE");
    online.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel utilizador = new JLabel("Utilizador:");
    JTextField user = new JTextField();

    painel.add(utilizador, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    painel.add(user, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    add(painel);
    add(online);
    add(offline);
}

}
```

O meu resultado do codigo foi este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um `GridLayout` simplesmente divide o espaço disponível no número especificado (no caso, 1 linha e 3 colunas) e faz com que cada elemento ocupe esse espaço todo. No seu caso isso dá dois problemas, pois:

1. A caixa de texto fica muito pequena, do mesmo tamanho de cada botão;
2. Os botões ocupam o espaço inteiro, ficando "esticados".

Além disso, noto que você colocou o label e caixa do utilizador dentro de um painel, e usou *este* painel no `GridLayout`. O ideal seria que o label ficasse no painel principal, e a caixa e os dois botões dentro dele.

Vou dar uma resposta parcial (pois não tenho como testar isso agora, e faz anos que não trabalho com Java, não estou familiarizado com as novas opções de *layout manager*), que resolve os problemas 2 e 3 mas não o 1. Vou também tentar arriscar um código pra resolver o 1, usando `GridBagLayout`, mas não posso garantir que funcionará pois minha memória anda meio falha...

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// O label vai no norte do cabeçalho
JLabel utilizador = new JLabel("Utilizador:");
add(utilizador, BorderLayout.NORTH);

// E o resto vai no centro
JPanel painel = new JPanel();
add(painel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// O centro se divide em 3
painel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

// A caixa de texto e os 3 botões vão no centro
JTextField user = new JTextField();
JPanel auxOnline = new JPanel();
JPanel auxOffline = new JPanel();

painel.add(user);
painel.add(auxOnline);
painel.add(auxOffline);

// Mas os botões não vão diretamente pro centro; em vez disso, um
// painel auxiliar é criado para cada um deles de modo que não estiquem.
auxOnline.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
auxOnline.add(online);
auxOffline.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
auxOffline.add(offline);
```

Para fazer com que a caixa de texto cresça e ocupe o maior espaço possível, mas os botões continuem do seu tamanho preferencial, uma alternativa é usar `GridBagLayout`. Especificar onde cada elemento fica é um pouco mais chato, mas o resultado final é uma flexibilidade bem maior no posicionamento:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// O label vai no norte do cabeçalho
JLabel utilizador = new JLabel("Utilizador:");
add(utilizador, BorderLayout.NORTH);

// E o resto vai no centro
JPanel painel = new JPanel();
add(painel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Em vez de Grid, usa GridBag
painel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); // Margem externa de todos os componentes

// Coloca a caixa de texto; cresce horizontalmente
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.weightx = 1;
painel.add(user, c);

// Coloca os botões; não cresce
c.weightx = 0;

c.gridx++;
painel.add(online, c); // Não precisa de painel auxiliar
c.gridx++;
painel.add(offline, c);
```

No fim das contas, ainda será um grid 1x3, mas a primeira coluna crescerá conforme o tamanho da janela, enquanto as duas outras manterão seu tamanho preferencial.

[Tutorial de `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) (em inglês)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!